# How to use notebook hard drive with Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ntfs

I had a notebook with Windows installed, after some time it has passed on. However i extracted hard drive to use it separately (and because there were some important things there)

When i attach it to Windows systems, it works fine. However, when i attach it to linux, it mounts as read-only or does not mount at all.

What can i do to make it read-writeeable from both systems?

Currently i sustect that reason is hard drive was a system one, but how exactly that causes problems eludes me.

Answer (score 2):

Hard drive has NTFS partion, I assume. Most Linux distributives doesn't have tools for NTFS write operation out of the box.

Install ntfs-3g on linux system:
https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/

Answer (score -2):

NTFS support is built-in in most Linux distributions out of the box, so the read-only problem in Linux is probably caused by the existing partitioning on the hard drive.

1. Backup all important files on the hard drive to another storage device.
2. Connect the hard drive and boot into Windows.
3. Install [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html) free version or use the [diskpart](https://commandwindows.com/diskpart.htm) command-line disk partitioning program that is built-in in Windows.
4. Reformat the hard drive as NTFS. **Warning**: This operation will overwrite all data that is stored on the hard drive.